# Delete text from backspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, backspace

I can't find tutorial that does this. I have...

```
UIbutton 
UItext.text
```

I want to make my own KEYBOARD user interface without iphone keyboard. I want to press the UIbutton(keyboard "delete" key or backspace) from text. Not ease the whole thing like `UIText.text = @""`. I've seen programmers give the wrong code.  I'm looking for something like Visual Basic Sendkeys `{Delete}`. How do I do this on iphone button? http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-os-where-the-delete-key-belongs/

For example:

```
Text1
Text<=
Tex<=
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement the following method to delete the last character.

```
- (NSString *)deleteLastChar:(NSString *)str {
    if (![str length]) return @""; 
    return [str substringToIndex:[str length]-1];
}
```

You can then use that on your text field's text property e.g:

```
textField.text = [self deleteLastChar:textField.text];
```

Comment: I assume somebody thought that `substringToIndex:` includes the character at the index and thus that this would return the whole string. That is, of course, not the case, so this answer is perfectly right AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([textField.text length] != 0) {
    textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length]-1];
}
```